# Debian sudo: account validation failure, is your account locked?

Tags: debian, locking, sudo, account

After an update && upgrade of a debian system I try to upgrade python withouth using sudo so when it try to create a new directory inside /usr/ it got blocked when I try to run it as sudo it returns

sudo: account validation failure, is your account locked?

I already look for some ideas but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but as there is no answer to this question and info on this error are very hard to find, I hope it helps to find one. For context, I'm on NixOS and I got the same error after a Linux kernel upgrade.

This issue is probably linked to some kind of corruption in your `/etc/pam.d/*` files. To be more specific, `/etc/pam.d/sudo`. In my case, this file was wiped. What I would recommend, is, if possible, to compare this file from an old version/working version of the system to your current file. If there is a diff, to overwrite the corrupted file with the old one. You will need root access to do this (using recovery mode maybe).

The same error can happen with any of the given file in /etc/pam.d/. For instance, if `$ su` return `su: Authentification failed`. Then it could be an issue with `/etc/pam.d/su` file.